# How to pass a network request to called activity?

Tags: android

In activity A I would like to start a network request which will fetch some data from internet. I would like to display the data in activity B. Since the request over network takes sometime and opening a new activity is also very time consuming I would like to optimize this two things and run them at the same time. So my plan is:

Activity A

- 1. start network request.
- 2. start activity B and somehow pass the network request

Activity B

- receive network request callbacks
- display progress bar
- display result upon receiving it

The problem is of course that I cannot pass pending request as parcelable object in intent. I understand this is a tricky problem but the the benefit is reduced double lag. At the moment I am using Aquery library to make network request but I will move away from it as it is not possible to cancel long running network request.
I guess the problem could be boiled down to: How to pass a network request to called activity?

Is this possible to do? How do I approach it?

Comment: I suggest instead of fetch data and pass the value to next Activity. You just move the network request to the next Activity and update your UI.

Comment: interesting question. there is definitely some gains if this can be achieved in some cool way. Don't know why your question is down voted.

Comment: Most downvotes originate from fact that people do not have a clue about the subject they are downvoting on.

Comment: While I don't always make a comment, a donwvote (in most cases) deserves a comment to help OP and audience to understand what you think is wrong with the post.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **[IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)**. Have a look at the documetation, you can start the service and then use **Broadcast** to send data to Activity-B